# How do I troubleshoot a vehicle that won't start?

Tags: starting, ignition

My 2000 Chevy truck lights all come on like normal but won't start there is nothing . I hooked 2 wires to the starter and hit them together and it started. Any idea what the problem is

Comment: Did it turn over or did it start and stay running?

Answer (score 5):

A car needs 3 things to start: Fuel, Air, & Spark. You can do try the following to either rule in or rule out the missing piece:

To make sure you're getting air and spark, try taking off the mass air flow cover from your manifold, and spray ***a little*** starter fluid directly into the intake, while attempting to start the car. If the car is getting a spark, the car should at least start because the air and fuel are coming in through the intake.

If the car doesn't start, you're likely not getting a spark.

If it starts and runs well, there may be a blockage in your air, which removing the air flow cover solved. You could visually check your air filter and air flow path.

If it starts, runs for a second or two, but stalls out - even after flooring the gas pedal after starting - It's possible there is no fuel getting to the cylinders.

This is just a very basic guide to point you in the right direction of the offending system that's keeping your car from starting.

---

In your specific case, your battery could be the culprit (may not be carrying enough current), or it could be the wires running from the battery to the starter. I would visually check the wires for damage.

Comment: Just to interject here - a number of immobilisers will stop electronic fuel injectors from working, so always keep that in mind. 

However, it appears that OP cannot even get the vehicle to turn over, so I'm inclined to think the battery. If all the lights go off on the dash when turning over - I'd bet a whiskey it's the battery

Answer (score 1):

Since shorting the starter worked it sounds like the issue is with your key/ignition.
Something isn't powering the starter when you turn the key?

Could also be bad power or ground wire to the starter.